# what to use with never, third form or first form

Tags: word-form

i always confused what to use with never.

I was taking to my co-worker and i had to tell her that HR never gave any party so i got confused what to use give or gave

> - never give any party or never gave any party ?
> - never give pays or never gave pays [just like my friend never pays tax]

Comment: It depends on what were you trying to say: that HR (Human Resources?) never gave a party before (cause there were a party recently for the first time) or that HR never has given a party

Comment: yes a kind of like she never gave a party since years ago

Comment: gave pay is not idiomatic. You either pay someone or you don't. You can look up and study: always, never, sometimes, often and other adverbs of frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on context.  Either you are saying it has never happened *in the past*, or you are saying it's a *general truth*.

Taking your second example first: it is a general truth that your friend doesn't pay tax, so use the present tense:

> My friend never **pays** any tax.

(Note it's *pays* and not *gives pay*.  "Gives pay" is not natural English.)

With your first example, the idiom is to *have* or to *throw* a party, not to give a party.  *Throw* usually takes an indirect object:

> My friend just **threw her mother** a surprise birthday party.

While *have* uses *for*:

> My friend just **had** a surprise birthday party **for her mother**.

In this case you're talking about *past events up to the present moment*, so use the past tense:

> Now I feel bad.  I never **threw** my mother any parties.  I should throw one this year.